# What is full URL for a post?

Tags: pages, title

What page is used for a post in Wordpress?  For example,

www.mysite.com/some-post-title/index.php

The index.php isn't valid.  What is actually after the last slash?

Comment: Usually nothing, that `some-post-title` part really depends on how you set up your permalinks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing after the slash. Do not see the address as something like a directory structure. It is just an address, a unique string to tell WordPress which content it should load.

That content will be loaded into any template, and that template again could be composed of multiple separate files from the theme.